# ZF2 + Doctrine2 - Form & Bind Entity - Params Null

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, entity, zend-framework2, zend-form

While working on one of my ZF2 controller, I got this error:

```
Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException
File: /var/www/microweb2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php:47
Message: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO quotes (name, email, phone_number, budget, content, date_posted, service_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null, null, null, null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null
```

Well, this seems like a pretty basic error but I can't find the solution. The process is this: I create my form to display it, then I bind it with an entity `Application\Entity\Quote`. Then I set my hydrator with a `DoctrineHydrator`. If the request is `POST`, I set my form values with the request values and I validate them with InputFilter. Unfortunately, if the `isValid()` return `true`, the DB return the error... WHY THE VALUES ARE NULL?

Here's my controller code: http://pastebin.com/JVK5xE9r

Here's my entity: http://pastebin.com/NhtaBNW9

Here's my `AbstractEntity`: http://pastebin.com/s4L7Cquu

Here's my form: http://pastebin.com/t7Kmzfk5

Here's my `AbstractForm`: http://pastebin.com/36WeyKBf

*There's too much code to include it in the question.*

The `get()` methods works for entities, and `set()` also. But that's the only problem I have! So I would like to know why.

If anyone can tell me why it doesn't work, it would be nice!

Comment: kindly post your controller here, as well as entity too, i cant open these, link if you post code here i may help you

Answer (score 2):

Ah i think i got what you are facing now, what you are doing is

```
 $quote = new \Application\Entity\Quote();
```

and then you are using

```
$form->bind($quote);
```

so on creating a new Object for **$quote** you are getting empty values. Where as you are using

```
 $form->bind($quote);
```

This function assumes that values are already present in **$quote (object)**. by practice **Bind()**  is usually used in Editing some form.

So if you are adding some thing you must Do Get/Set or Use **exchangearray()** or w/e seems ok to you. But if you are going to **Edit** then you must get Id and do something like this

```
 $quote=$em(this is GetEntityManagerObject)->getRepository->find($id);
```

and then use **bind()**. With this approach you dont need to do **$quote = new \Application\Entity\Quote();**.

Comment: Well, I tried to use the `setOptions()` method (which is essentially `exchangeArray()` and it didn't work... Still settings parameters to `NULL`... Any other idea? Here's my new controller code: [http://pastebin.com/9uZ4Trz7](http://pastebin.com/9uZ4Trz7)

Comment: I dont know why you are using setOptions() on Entity Object,setOptions() is a form Object. So you need to call it with Form.

Comment: Well, it's my way to exchangeArray... I prefer using `setOptions()`, it does the same thing :p

`public function setOptions($options = array())
    {
        foreach ($options as $propertyName => $propertyValue) {
            $methodName = 'set' . ucfirst($propertyName);
            if (method_exists($this, $methodName)) {
                $this->$methodName($propertyValue);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }`

Comment: I just checked your entity there is no SetOptions() in your entity update your code so your above mention approach may work there.  $quote->setOptions($form->getData()); means you are calling function from entity and i cant see any function there.

Comment: Well, the `setOptions()` method is in the `AbstractEntity` class... So all of my entity gets it... If it wasn't working, I would get an error...

Comment: Can you tell me why you are using AbstractEntity ?

Comment: Because I use magic methods like `__get` and `__set`... And because as long as my website is not done, I don't wanna generate entities with getter/setter from the Doctrine CLI...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34183/discussion-between-frederick-marcoux-and-noobie-php)

Comment: Well From what i know i think getData() return Object By Default, And setOptions() Requires array(). So you need to get a work around for it.